# useCallback should not be called when deleting an element from an array

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the problem that when I press the icon to delete an image, the previously selected image, which is in the same array as the one to be deleted, loses its style. I thought I'd use the useCallback function to prevent this, but it doesn't do anything yet

```
import uuid from "react-uuid";

const [image, setImage] = useState<Blob[]>([]);
const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState<Blob | null>(null);

const deleteImage = (singleImage: Blob) => {
  const filteredList = Array.from(image).filter(function (img) {
    return img !== singleImage;
  });
  setImage(filteredList);
};

const memoCall = useCallback((img: Blob) => {
  console.log("memoCall");
  if (selectedImage === img) {
    setSelectedImage(null);
  } else {
    setSelectedImage(img);
  }
}, [selectedImage]);

return 
{image?.length > 0 &&
  image.map((img, index) =>
  selectedImage === img ? (
  <div
    className="w-full h-[300px] relative border-red-500 border-4"
    key={uuid()}
    onClick={() => memoCall(img)}
  >...</div>
) : (
  <div
    className="w-full h-[300px] relative"
    key={uuid()}
    onClick={() => memoCall(img)}
  >...</div> 
)}
);
```

Comment: Try to use different key instead of index. Using index causes layout issues

Comment: @Sagar Just tried it with uuid(), still have the problem (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-uuid)

Comment: Could you please attach jsFiddle or code sandbox link to try this out ?

Comment: The key needs to be stable. You’re generating a new key the whole time.

Comment: @flq How should I generate a unique key? The images are selected locally and do not come from a DB. What is a unique key in this case?